# DataTable JQuery | Reinitialize and getting the column & row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data table in my page with the status column and view details column. after clicking view details it will pop up a modal, the modal contains a dropdown for status that when changed a certain value in the database will change. However after closing the modal the value in the datatable doesn't change. How can I reload the data table without reinitializing it, or how to get the column & row that i clicked so that I can change the value of the certain column & row. I have this code for initializing the datatable on doc.ready

```
 function createTable(data){
        for (i in data){
            var message = "<tr>";
            var statusHolder = "";


            if(data[i].status == "open"){
                statusHolder = "Open";
            } else if (data[i].status == "resolved"){
                statusHolder = "Resolved";
            } else {
                statusHolder = "Closed";
            }
            var id = data[i].id;
            message+= "<td>" + statusHolder + "</td>";
            message+= "<td><input id = 'ticketId' type ='hidden' value = " + data[i].id +" /><input type = 'hidden' id = 'support-type-name' value = 'call-back'/><a href='javascript:retrieveCommentsInfo(" + data[i].id +")' id='view-ticket-info'>" + " View details" + "</span></td>";          
            message+= "<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>";


            $("#callback-request-body").append(message);


        }

        $("#callback-request-table").dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [ {"visible": false, "targets": [6]},
                          ]
        });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered! So I used this created a function the will reintialize datatables.

```
function reInitializeDataTables(){
    callbackTable.destroy();
    $("#callback-request-body").empty();
    retrieveCallBackRequests();

    contactUsTable.destroy();
    $("#contactus-table-body").empty();
    retrieveContactUsMessages();
}
```

I'll just use .destroy() function to the datatable and then remove all contents of the body of the data table.